# Настройка php .Отправка формы на почту

Tags: javascript, php

есть лендинг на нем 2 формы заказа и 1 всплывающее окно "обратного звонка". Нужно чтоб на почту приходило письмо с информацией заполненных полей в формах.У меня ничего не приходит. Думаю что проблема в `send.php` так как сам ее пытался сделать.Помогите пожалуйста.
есть скрипт `send.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('#sendbnt').click(function(){

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();

    if ((name =="") || (phone ==""))
    {
        alert('Заполните поля');
    }

    else 
    {
        $.post('./send.php', {func: 'send', name: name, phone: phone}, function(){
            $('.modal_mess').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, '3000');            
      });
    }
});
 $('#sendbnt2').click(function(){

    var name = $('#name2').val();
    var phone = $('#phone2').val();
    if ((name =="") || (phone ==""))
    {
        alert('Заполните поля');
    }

    else 
    {
        $.post('./send.php', {func: 'send', name: name, phone: phone}, function(){
            $('.modal_mess').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, '3000'); 
      });
    }
});

  $('#sendmod').click(function(){

    var name = $('#namemod').val();
    var phone = $('#phonemod').val();

    if ((name =="") || (phone ==""))
    {
        alert('Заполните поля');
    }

    else 
    {
        $.post('./send.php', {func: 'send', name: name, phone: phone}, function(){
            $('.modal_mess').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, '3000'); 
      });
    }
});

});
```

есть send.php

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
/* Устанавливаем e-mail Кому и от Кого будут приходить письма */    
    $to = "admin@site.ua"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, куда будут приходить письма  
    $from = "admin@site.ua"; // Здесь нужно написать e-mail, от кого будут приходить письма, например no-reply@epicblog.net

/* Указываем переменные, в которые будет записываться информация с формы */
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта Epic Blog";//Фиксированная тема письма


/* Переменная, которая будет отправлена на почту со значениями, вводимых в поля */
$mail_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте! 
Было отправлено сообщение с сайта! 
Имя отправителя: $name 
Номер телефона: $phone 
Чтобы ответить на письмо, создайте новое сообщение, скопируйте электронный адрес и вставьте в поле Кому.";  

$headers = "From: $from \r\n";

/* Отправка сообщения, с помощью функции mail() */
    mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
}
?>
```

Код  формы на сайте.первая

```
<div class="callwrap">
            <div class="call">
                <h5>Закажите обратный звонок</h5>
                <input type="text" class="txt" id="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required="">
                <input type="text" class="txt" id="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required="">
                <a class="btn" id="sendbnt">Заказать звонок</a>
                <h6>или просто позвоните нам</h6>
                <h7><a href="tel:(096) 008-04-29" style="color: #fff;">(066) 008-04-29</a></h7>
            </div>
        </div>
```

вторая

```
<div class="call">
                <h5>Получить консультацию сейчас?</h5>
                <input type="text" class="txt" id="name2" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                <input type="text" class="txt" id="phone2" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
                <a class="btn" id="sendbnt2">Заказать звонок</a>
                <h6>или просто позвоните нам</h6>
                <h7><a href="tel:(099) 497-79-99" style="color: #fff;">(097) 427-79-99</a></h7>
            </div>
```

Всплывающее окно "обратного звонка"

```
<div class="zakaz">
            <a class="close">Закрыть</a>
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="15px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="txt11" id="namemod" placeholder="Укажите имя" required="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="txt11" id="phonemod" placeholder="Укажите телефон" required="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="70px;">
                        <span class="btn11" id="sendmod">Отправить</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <h3>или позвоните нам<br><a href="tel:(099) 427-79-79">(097) 427-79-99</a></h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: if($_POST['submit']) { echo '<pre>'.var_export($_POST,true); die();

Ввел вместо if($_POST['submit']) {


ничего не происходит. На сайте пишет спасибо за отправку, а на почту ничего не приходит

Comment: Скрипт рабочий должен быть ,взят с другого сайта .Я не смог раздобыть и php от него....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя нет в пост запросе переменной $_POST['submit'] и как минимум этот if не отрабатывает. Замени на

```
if($_POST){
```

ну или на одно из if($_POST['func']){ , if($_POST['name']){, if($_POST['phone']){

Comment: Все подставил if($_POST['func']){  , все заработало